# Не получается подсоединить картинку к таблице Js

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование

Нужно сделать таблицу с 6 элементами, все эти элементы - картинки. Но не удается это сделать, картинки сами по себе, буд то ничего я и не делал. Вот код:

```html
<body>
  <table id="mytable" border="1">
    <th>Картинка1</th>
    <th>Картинка2</th>
    <th>Картинка3</th>
    <th>Картинка4</th>
    <th>Картинка5</th>
    <th>Картинка6</th>
  </table>
  <img src="winter.jpg" width="100" height="150" id="winter">
  <img src="summer.jpg" width="100" height="150" id="summer">
  <img src="fall.jpg" width="100" height="150" id="fall">
  <img src="spring.jpg" width="100" height="150" id="spring">
  <img src="france.jpg" width="100" height="150" id="france">
  <img src="lion.jpg" width="100" height="150" id="lion">
  <script>
    table1 = document.getElementById('mytable');
    row1 = table1.insertRow(table1.rows.length);
    cell1 = row1.insertCell(row1.cells.length);
    cell1.innerHTML = document.getElementById('winter');
    cell1 = row1.insertCell(row1.cells.length);
    cell1.innerHTML = document.getElementById('summer');
    cell1 = row1.insertCell(row1.cells.length);
    cell1.innerHTML = document.getElementById('spring');
    cell1 = row1.insertCell(row1.cells.length);
    cell1.innerHTML = document.getElementById('fall');
    cell1 = row1.insertCell(row1.cells.length);
    cell1.innerHTML = document.getElementById('france');
    cell1 = row1.insertCell(row1.cells.length);
    cell1.innerHTML = document.getElementById('lion');
</script>
</body>
```

Надеюсь, поможете. Это для колледжа, поэтому можно без JQuery и прочих библиотек?

Comment: Что за хитрые манёвры? Зачем вам второй аккаунт?

Comment: НАсколько я понимаю у вас начались контрольные работы ?

Comment: На том пишет, что нельзя задавать вопросы)

Comment: @EzioMercer а может это разные аккаунты, но они учаться в одном колледже, на одном курсе и попались одинаковые задачи?

Comment: @ПростаMiha Учитывая то что было в предыдущем вопросе, такое ощущение, друг у друга списывают (если, конечно, это не второй аккаунт) :)

Comment: Да)) я просто не люблю WebDev, поэтому особо не учил его. C++ мне заходит больше

Comment: @Andrey посмотрите ваш предыдущий ответ)

Comment: @ПростаMiha Погорячился, вы правы)

Comment: Так поможете?) Немного изменил код, теперь ошибка [objectHTMLImageElement]

Comment: Замените `.innerHTML` на метод `.append(element)`

Comment: @Andrey "На том пишет, что нельзя задавать вопросы) " --- улучшайте качество вопросов значит. ЗА мультяшество  может прилететь бан %)

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужен `append` вместо `innerHTML`:

```html
<body>
  <table id="mytable" border="1">
    <th>Картинка1</th>
    <th>Картинка2</th>
    <th>Картинка3</th>
    <th>Картинка4</th>
    <th>Картинка5</th>
    <th>Картинка6</th>
  </table>
  <img src="winter.jpg" width="100" height="150" id="winter">
  <img src="summer.jpg" width="100" height="150" id="summer">
  <img src="fall.jpg" width="100" height="150" id="fall">
  <img src="spring.jpg" width="100" height="150" id="spring">
  <img src="france.jpg" width="100" height="150" id="france">
  <img src="lion.jpg" width="100" height="150" id="lion">
  <script>
    table1 = document.getElementById('mytable');
    row1 = table1.insertRow(table1.rows.length);
    cell1 = row1.insertCell(row1.cells.length);
    cell1.append(document.getElementById('winter'));
    cell1 = row1.insertCell(row1.cells.length);
    cell1.append(document.getElementById('summer'));
    cell1 = row1.insertCell(row1.cells.length);
    cell1.append(document.getElementById('spring'));
    cell1 = row1.insertCell(row1.cells.length);
    cell1.append(document.getElementById('fall'));
    cell1 = row1.insertCell(row1.cells.length);
    cell1.append(document.getElementById('france'));
    cell1 = row1.insertCell(row1.cells.length);
    cell1.append(document.getElementById('lion'));
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Спасибо тебе) уже 2 раз помог, все отлично работает) 2 минуты, отмечу как правильный (там через 3 минуты можна)